Can someone explain these Slokas?
In the parashar smriti and daksh smriti it is said




I am suffering from incontinence which is why I think maybe this sloka can be helpful in my situation anyone please help

I) Parāsara Smriti(पराशर स्मृति) is the Dharma Sāstra which talks of the rules of good conduct, cleanliness, and religious rites, which may be beneficially followed and observed by men in this age of kali (कलि युग/kali Yuga) [Ch-1 Sloka-2]
Parāsara Smriti [chapter-7] discusses about purification of Vessels and utensils. The final 3 sutra are given below:
Beware-1: Sloka number is 7.43 rather than 7.42 as OP mentioned.
Beware-2: Sloka-7.41 and Sloka-7.42 are also displayed because they too are relevant to sloka-7.43, the one which has been displayed and wanted by OP.

Parāsara Smriti [chapter-7, slokas: 41-43] 

देशभङ्गे प्रवासे वा व्याधिषु व्यसनेष्वपि ।
रश्चेदेव स्वदेहादि पश्चाद्धर्मं समाचरेत् ॥ ७.४१ ॥

During a civil commotion, or in exile, or when ill, or in misfortune,
the first consideration is to preserve one's life ; 
practice of religion should at the time be postponed. ॥ 7.41 ॥

येन केन च धर्मेण मृदुना दारुणेन च।
उदरेदीनमात्मानं समर्थोधर्ममाचरेत् ॥ ७.४२॥

By any kind of conduct, soft or cruel, one should deliver himself from  a distressed
state; the practice of religious rites ought to be left for a period
when he is equal to the task. ॥ 7.42 ॥    

आपत्काले तु निस्तीर्णे शौचाचारन्तु चिन्तयेत् । 
शुद्धि समुहरेत् पश्चात् स्वस्थो धर्म समाचरेत् ॥ ७.४३ ॥ 

After the misfortune is over, one should think of purification and religious rites.
Thereafter purity may be recovered by him. He ought to practice religion
when his troubles are past. ॥ 7.43 ॥


Since you have been suffering from Incontinence, you can't sustain the purification needed for Nitya Karma/Shat Karma (daily obligatory duties to be performed from dawn to dusk). The final three slokas of Parāsara Smriti approves in order to waive those daily duty (Nitya Karma/नित्य कर्म) until you recover physically. There are six rites, a brahmin should perform daily in Kali Yuga, which are:

संध्या स्नानं जपो होमो देवतानां च पूजनम्। आतिथ्यं वैश्वदेवं च
षट्कर्माणि दिने दिने॥ १.३९ ॥
Meaning: According to Parāsara Smriti [1.39], sandhyā-snāna [bathing at sandyā time, viz. morning and evening], japa [Gayatri
Mantra Repetition], havana [agni hotram/fire sacrifice], vedādhyayana [recitation of
Veda/self-study], devata poojan [Shiva-Vishnuvādhi pooja], atiti-seva
[entertaining guests] and bali-vaishvadeva-yajna  [Offer food to
those who are in need] are the six daily duties (nitya karma/shat karma)
applicable particularly in Kali Yuga(कलि युग).
-Parāsara Smriti: Ch-1 Sloka-39

Beware-3: Manu [10.75] says that study[अध्ययनम्], teaching of[अध्यापनं], and officiating as priests at[यजनं], religious sacrifices[याजनं], and giving[दान] and taking gifts[प्रतिग्रहश्] are the six religious duties enjoined on a brahman in the Satya Yuga.
Therefore, one need not think of laws of decorum or cleanliness when in distress. First get rid of trouble then practice virtues (such as Nitya Karma/Shat Karma) [7.43].
II) Daksha Smriti(पराशर स्मृति) [chapter-6] addresses personal impurities arising from births and deaths within the family. The final three slokas  of this chapter from Daksha Smriti [Slokas: 6.18-20] are reproduced below and the first one is OP asked for:

Daksha Smriti [chapter-6, slokas: 8-10] 

स्वस्थकाले त्विदं सर्वमशौचं परिकीर्तितम् ।
आपद्गतस्य​ सर्वस्य​ सूतके न तु सूतकम् ॥ ६.१८ ॥

svastakale tvidam sarvamashoucam parikīrtitam ।
āpadgatasya sarvasya sūtake na tu sūtakam ॥ 6.18 ॥

All the impurities have been spoken when a person being healthy.
Even on the occasion of child-birth during a calamity [आपद्गत/distress], 
there is no impurity since cleanliness can't be upheld. ॥ 6.18 ॥

यज्ञे प्रवर्तमाने तु जायेतार्थ म्रियेत वा।
पूर्व संकल्पिते कार्ये न दोष स्तत्र विद्यते ॥ ६.१९ ॥ 

The impurity [दोष] of birth or death taken place during yajna, will not affect 
sankalpa [सङ्कल्प/solemn vow/determination to perform any ritual observance]
taken before beginning of yajna in order to uphold yajna-dharma. ॥ 6.19 ॥

यज्ञकाले विवाहे च देवयागे तथैव च​।    
हूयमाने तथा चाग्नौ नापि सूतकम् ॥ ६.२० ॥

There would be no impurity, consequent on a birth or death,
when a sacrifice is being performed, or a marriage is being solemnized,
when there is a revolution in the country, or a Homa is being performed. ॥ 6.20 ॥


Both Parāsara Smriti and Daksha Smriti speak with the same tone but in different contexts about waiver of not only cleanliness but also observing every day dharma such as Nitya Karma or Shat karma during the complete period of distress or calamity. However, Parāsara Smriti goes on step ahead and says this in the context of Kali Yuga!

I pray Goddess Durgā Parameshwari to bless you for speedy recovery from
your suffering (incontinence).

Good Luck!
